# I can't update this global variable to increment by one each time the function has ran

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a function triggerCards that I want to run only for the amount of times that is equal to have how many cards I am running (threeDSCards.length).

The page keeps thinking row = 0 instead of updating to the current row number. I can not use a for loop for a few reasons.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
threeDSCards.length = 2;

window.row = 0;

        function triggerCards(row){
        i = row;
        $("input[name='cc_number']").delay(5000).focus();
        $("input[name='cc_number']").val(threeDSCards[i]["cardnumber"]);

        $("select[name='expmonth']").delay(5000).focus();

        if(threeDSCards[i]["expMonth"] < 10)
        {
            var month = '0';
            month += threeDSCards[i]["expMonth"];
        }
        else
        {
            var month = threeDSCards[i]["expMonth"];
        }

        $("select[name='expmonth']").val(month);

        $("select[name='expyear']").delay(5000).focus();
        $("select[name='expyear']").val(threeDSCards[i]["expYear"]);

        $("input[name='cc_cvv']").delay(5000).focus();

        initRun(row);
    }

    triggerCards(row);

    function initRun(row){
    if(row < threeDSCards.length){
    console.log("Row:" + row);
    window.row = row + 1;
    triggerCards(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` statement:

```
while(row < threeDSCards.length){
triggerCards(row);
row++
}
```

Comment: I can't use a loop because initRun uses asynchronous code. The loop would run faster than asynchronous code because there is no way to see when that asynchronous code is done executing.